# Unexpected output in fmt.Println() function

Tags: go, refactoring, println

I'm starting with golang (total noob), and I'm using a simple wrapper function for `fmt.Println(str)`, just because it's shorter and I'm more used to it:

```
func echo(str ...interface{}) {
  fmt.Println(str)
}
```

The thing is that the output for `echo("Hello")` is `[Hello]` instead of `Hello`.

Am I missing some syntax detail here? How can I change the function to work as expected?

Besides the actual *need* for this function, I'm interested in the language-specific details about this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you send to `fmt.Println` parameter as a slice, but not as varadic.

Change your method to :

```
func echo(str ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(str...)
}
```

And it will work as you expect.

Check topic **Arguments to variadic functions** from [this site](https://programming.guide/go/three-dots-ellipsis.html).